# Can I connect my mixer's headphone out to an audio interface

Tags: recording, audio, mixer

I am trying to set up a low budget recording. I already have an 8-channel mixer and I was thinking about recording drums using 6 or 7 piece drum mic kits using my mixer, then connect the mixer's headphone out to my Scarlett 2i4's input.

As much as I want to try this myself, my mixer's power cable was not included (I still have to go back to the shop where I bought it).

Is my idea possible?

Comment: Most mixers have a pair of of outputs (stereo) labeled "main out" (or similar), usually you'd use those to set to the interface rather than the signal from the  headphones out.

Comment: there may be impedance issues using headphones instead of normal line out (?)

Comment: It indeed has 2 XLR line outs, I guess I can hook both of them to my scarlett 2i4's input channels. Thanks for the information, I will experiment with what I have

Comment: Use the normal line outputs from the mixer -- the results will be much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will definitely work, however, you will be stuck with the mix you have.  Since you're taking multiple inputs and sending them through the mixer and into a single channel on your interface, you won't be able to go back and set the volumes for different microphones differently, or add any plugins/effects to single microphones.  Because of this, you will probably need to do a lot of experimenting, recording with some settings, listening back, making adjustments, and repeat.  I've seen some people accomplish a great sound with this approach but it is very limiting since you can't adjust individual mics after the fact.  With the 2i2, you should have two inputs, so I might recommend experimenting a little and choosing a microphone to send direct to the interface and allow you to have a little control over it after the fact.  This would most likely work best with your kick or snare mic.  Depending on your mixer, you may be able to create a couple groups of channels and send them separately to the interface, allowing you to separate some of the mics from each other.

Comment: Sounds wonderful! as a matter of fact the mixer I have has 2 audio interface inputs as well, so that makes 3 extra inputs for me to work with and set individually. Thanks for the information

Comment: If I understand correctly, you may not be able to do that as you're expecting.  You will only be able to use one interface at a time and the 2i2 will only allow two inputs, so you'll only be able to record two tracks at a time and be able to edit them after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how many inputs the scarlett has but if your mixer has direct channel outs, Id use those to go into the scarlett, or if your mixer has submixes, (most hve at least 4) you could send your kick and snare to sub 1 and 2 and send toms and cymbals to 3 & 4. some level adjusting will need to take place but I would try to get as many drums on as many tracks as possible, unless you are trying to get a stereo mix of the drums , then I would just come out of the main outs.